# Trouble Connecting Remote JADE Container to Main Container

Tags: java, agents-jade, multi-agent

'I m trying to establish communication between a main JADE container running on one machine and a secondary remote container running on another machine within the same network. However, I'm encountering issues with connecting the remote container to the main one. Here's my setup:

I have a main container running with the following profile:

```
import jade.core.Profile;
import jade.core.ProfileImpl;
import jade.core.Runtime;
import jade.wrapper.AgentContainer;

public class PlatformMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define platform parameters
        String PLATFORM_IP = "IP address";
        int PLATFORM_PORT = 1099;
        String PLATFORM_ID = "MyPlatform"; 

        Runtime rt = Runtime.instance();
        // Platform
        Profile pMain = new ProfileImpl(PLATFORM_IP, PLATFORM_PORT, PLATFORM_ID);

        System.out.println("Launching a main-container..." + pMain);
        AgentContainer mainContainerRef = rt.createMainContainer(pMain);

        // Container
        String containerName = "MyContainer1";
        Profile pContainer = new ProfileImpl(PLATFORM_IP, PLATFORM_PORT, PLATFORM_ID);
        pContainer.setParameter(Profile.CONTAINER_NAME, containerName);
        pContainer.setParameter(Profile.GUI,"true");
        System.out.println("Launching container " + containerName);
        AgentContainer containerRef = rt.createAgentContainer(pContainer);

        // RMA
        createMonitoringAgents(mainContainerRef);

        System.out.println("Platform initialized successfully");
        createMyAgent(containerRef);
    }

    private static void createMonitoringAgents(AgentContainer container) {
        // Implement method to create monitoring agents
    }

    private static void createMyAgent(AgentContainer container) {
        // Implement method to create your agent
    }
}
```

```
public class SecondaryRemoteContainer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java -jar YourJarFileName.jar <main_container_ip>");
            return;
        }
        
        String secondaryContainerIP = "localhost"; 
        int secondaryContainerPort = 1099; 
        String secondaryContainerID = "SecondaryContainer"; 
        
        String mainContainerIP = args[0]; 

        Runtime rt = Runtime.instance();

        // Platform
        Profile secondaryContainerProfile = new ProfileImpl(secondaryContainerIP, secondaryContainerPort, secondaryContainerID);
        secondaryContainerProfile.setParameter(Profile.MAIN_HOST, mainContainerIP); 
        System.out.println("Launching the secondary container..." + secondaryContainerProfile);
        AgentContainer secondaryContainerRef = rt.createMainContainer(secondaryContainerProfile); 

        System.out.println("Secondary container initialized successfully");
    }
}
```

When I run the secondary remote container on my local machine, it connects successfully to the main container. However, when I try to run it on another machine within the same network, I encounter the following error:

> Error adding ICP jade.imtp.leap.JICP.JICPPeer@5eb5c224[Error: Not possible to launch JADE on a remote host (ip). Check the -host and -local-host options.].
> Communication failure while joining agent platform: No ICP active
> jade.core.IMTPException: No ICP active

I've ensured that both machines are connected to the same Wi-Fi network. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?